# Child class of EF Entity not being committed on the DBContext because it is not part of the model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, dbcontext

I am using EF6. I created an entity in the EF model which acts as a super class called AppUser containing all the properties I want to generate in the database. However, I created another class called AppUserM inheriting from AppUser; the child class has several methods for some UI operations. 
See the AppUser class below:

```
[Table("appUser")]
public class AppUser
{
    public AppUser()
    {
        this._AccessRights = new HashSet<AccessRight>();
        this._ActivityLog = new HashSet<ActivityLog>();
    }
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int userId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [DisplayName("Username")]
    public string username { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [MaxLength(2000)]
    [DisplayName("Password")]
    public string password { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(4000)]
    [DisplayName("FullName")]
    public string fullname { get; set; }
    public bool isADUser { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BankBranch")]
    public int branchId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AppRole")]
    public int roleId { get; set; }
    public virtual BankBranch BankBranch { get; set; }
    public virtual AppRole AppRole { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AccessRight> _AccessRights { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ActivityLog> _ActivityLog { get; set; }

}
```

the child class is shown below:

```
public class AppUserM : AppUser
{
    public void Add()
    {
        using (var cntx = new JEntityDbContext())
        {
            cntx.AppUsers.Add(this);
            cntx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    public void Read()
    { 

    }
}
```

Executing this raises an exception at the Add() method of the AppUserM exactly at   cntx.AppUsers.Add(this) see the implementation below;

```
     AppUserM user = new AppUserM
     {
          username = "Hakeem",
          password = "pass",
          roleId = 1,
          isADUser = false,
          fullname = "Ojulari Hakeem Olusegun"
     };
     user.Add();
```

The exception is :

*Additional information: The entity type AppUserM is not part of the model for the current context.*

I don't want to map the classes in the Add() method like this

```
AppUser user = new AppUser {username = this.username};
```

then this after

```
cntx.AppUsers.Add(user);
```

I want to minimize typing time and ensure efficiency. Is there any better way to achieve this. Thanks for your contributions

Comment: Kindly note that I could as well do **Add(AppUser user)** which I don't want to because I might want to add some properties to AppUserM for internal manipulation within the method before committing.

Comment: I don't expect that EF can handle this, since EF creates proxies for your entity classes (to handle lazy loading and such by overriding your virtual navigation props). So adding another layer of inheritance won't work. Also, how do you expect EF to return any instances of type `AppUserM` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't expect that EF can handle this, since EF creates proxies for your entity classes (to handle lazy loading and such by overriding your virtual navigation props).

I would just add the methods to the existing `AppUser` class.

```
[Table("appUser")]
public class AppUser
{
    public AppUser()
    {
        this._AccessRights = new HashSet<AccessRight>();
        this._ActivityLog = new HashSet<ActivityLog>();
    }
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int userId { get; set; }
    // ... other properties

    public void Add()
    {
        using (var cntx = new JEntityDbContext())
        {
            cntx.AppUsers.Add(this);
            cntx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    public void Read()
    { 

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying adding the methods on the model entity will not raise any issue on the context ?

Comment: Correct, that is no problem whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks so much. Can I instead split the AppUser with 'Partial' ?

Comment: Yep! If you name it like `AppUser.cs` and `AppUser.Custom.cs` (or something else instead of `Custom`), then Resharper won't complain either.

Comment: But my design wouldn't let me. The context is in another project different from the model (the entity). Creating a partial class for AppUser in Entity Project is not achievable bcos I need to reference the context (in another project which is already referencing Entity assembly). Any better way of separating the methods from the model?

Comment: I think you can solve this with extension methods, in the assembly where you would have put the 'AppUserM' class.